# Does Stripe re-run $0/$1 authorisation when the same credit card is attached to another customer object?

Tags: stripe-payments, credit-card

Stripe runs the authorisation when a card gets attached to a customer. Is it re-run when another payment source is created using the same credit card data and then attached to another customer object? Additionally, is the authorisation re-run when the same credit card gets re-attached to the same, single customer? (e.g. when someone deletes and then attaches again the same card data to a customer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with Stripe support and the card is authorised every time it gets attached to a customer. So if the same card is attached to multiple customers, it's authorised many times.